# How to set a style on ::after of one element from another hovered child element

Tags: html, css, sass, navbar, scss-mixins

I am using SCSS and the Bootstrap 4 navbar on my pages with certain `.nav-item` elements being toggles for dropdown menus.

When hovering over the `.dropdown-toggle` element, I want to apply `transform: rotate(180deg)` on the arrow of the toggle which is contained in `.dropdown-toggle::after`.

When setting the transform style on `dropdown-toggle:hover::after`, the arrow rotates fine but when the mouse is moved over the dropdown menu itself, the arrow rotates back to its old position. I want to keep the arrow rotated even when hovering over the dropdown items.

I tried different ways of applying the style on `dropdown-toggle::after` when the `dropdown-toggle` or the `dropdown-menu` are hovered but it only works on when doing

```
@mixin rotate180 {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.dropdown-toggle:hover::after {
    @include rotate180;
}
```

How can I make the `:hover` apply the rotate mixin to `.dropdown-toggle::after` also when the `dropdown-menu` is hovered?

Comment: If what you're trying to do is to rotate the dropdown caret, you can do so by adding the class `dropup` to the `btn-group` wrapper: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropup-variation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to @Periplo, all I had to do was surround my `dropdown-toggle` with `<div class='dmenu-toggle-container'>` and add an event handler for hover on the `.nav-item` to add & remove the class `dropup`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-item').hover(function() {
        $(this).children('.dmenu-toggle-container').addClass('dropup');
    }, function() {
        $(this).children('.dmenu-toggle-container').removeClass('dropup');
    });

});
```